# Dynamic link that parses to the element I type

Tags: javascript, dom

my goal is to type a stock symbol in the search bar and have a dynamic way for a link to be attached to the result. For example, when I search for FLWS, a element appears, like the one below, and when I click on that element it takes me to a specific page. So when I type FLWS in the search bar it allows me to go to this url: https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/FLWS/quote and when I type MSFT it allows me to go to https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/MSFT/quote

Thank you in advance.

[image]

My jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9afw1wq9

So my question is how do I make a dynamic link that parses to the element I type. I have this so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- inserting jquery -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <style>
        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        #myInput {
            //background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
            background-position: 10px 12px;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            width: 100%;
            font-size: 16px;
            padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
            margin-bottom: 12px;
        }

        #myUL {
            list-style-type: none;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }

        #myUL li a {
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
            margin-top: -1px; /* Prevent double borders */
            background-color: #f6f6f6;
            padding: 12px;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size: 18px;
            color: black;
            display: block
        }

        #myUL li a:hover:not(.header) {
            background-color: #eee;
        }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h2>My Portfolio</h2>
    <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for a Stock Symbol.." title="Type in a name">
    <ul id="myUL">
        <li><a href="#">Christina</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Cindy</a></li>

        <!-- Starting the Stock Test -->
        <li><a href="#">FLWS</a></li>
    </ul>
    <script>

        function myFunction() {
            var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
            input = document.getElementById("myInput");
            console.log(input);
            filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
            ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
            li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
            for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
                a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
                if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                    li[i].style.display = "";
                } else {
                    li[i].style.display = "none";

                }
            }
            //Returning the result
            console.log(filter);

            var parser = document.createElement('a');
            //End result should look like: https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/VNOM/quote
            parser.href = "https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/";

            parser.StockName = filter;
            console.log("Parser StockName: " + parser.StockName);

            var url = parser.href;
            var stockName = parser.StockName;
            var result = url + stockName;

            //concat quote to the end of the url
            var quoteAdd = "/quote";
            result = result + quoteAdd
            console.log("quote: " + quoteAdd);
            console.log("Final url: " + result);

            //counting letters in the filter
            var count = filter.replace(/[^A-Z]/gi, "").length;
            console.log(count);
            if (count == 2 || count == 3 || count == 4 && filter){
                if($("#myUL").length) {
                    console.log("nested if result: " + result);

                    /*  I need to find the element that i searched for, then add the result url to the button.
                        For example, when i search for FLWS, i click on that tag to take me to a new page.
                     */

                    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
                    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
                    console.log(li);

                    var result1 = document.getElementById('li');
                    console.log("nested result After: " + result);
                    console.log("result1: " + result1);
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Would you mind creating a snippet rather than dumping the source code into your question. This will allow myself and others to run the source code to better understand the problem and maybe explain the reason it isn't functioning as intended with a solution. Thank you.

Comment: Sure. Give me a second

Comment: I added the jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is functional till the url construction. You just need to add the result to the document. see the last two lines.

```
if (count == 2 || count == 3 || count == 4 && filter){
    if($("#myUL").length) {
        console.log("nested if result: " + result);

        /*  I need to find the element that i searched for, then add the result url to the button.
            For example, when i search for FLWS, i click on that tag to take me to a new page.
         */

        ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
        li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
        console.log(li);

        var result1 = document.getElementById('li');
        console.log("nested result After: " + result);
        console.log("result1: " + result1);
        var resultDiv = "<li><a href=" + "'" + result + "'" + ">" + filter + "</a></li>"
        $("#myUL").append(resultDiv);
    }
}
```